# How am I suppose to update mongodb and ElasticSearch at the same time more effectively?

Tags: python, mongodb, elasticsearch, apache-kafka

Data are from kafka, after handling two fields, I want to update these two fields into mongodb and elasticsearch, but the cost is a little bit high, so how am I suppose to improve it? I'm using python by the way.

```
def update_mongodb(field1, field2):
    # update operation

def update_es(field1, field2):
    # update operation

if __name__ == "__main__":
    consumer = utils.kafka_conn()
    consumer.subscribe(('topic_name',))
    for message in consumer:
        # handling two fields
        field1 = handling_field1()
        field2 = handling_field2()
        update_mongodb(field1, field2)
        update_es(field1, field2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Elastic especially is really bad with numerous single updates from my experience. What you want to use elastic's [bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

All you have to do is construct an array with the updates you want

```
[
   { "index" : { "_index" : "index_name", "_id" : "1" } }
   { "field1" : "value1", "field2": "value2" }
]
```

like so:

```
elastic_bulk = []
for message in consumer:
    # handling two fields
    field1 = handling_field1()
    field2 = handling_field2()
    update_mongodb(field1, field2)
    elastic_bulk.append({"index": {"_index": "index_name", "_id": message['_id']}})
    elastic_bulk.append({"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"})

bulk_es(elastic_bulk)
```

I would just add  that this will break the 1 to 1 syncing you imagine between Mongo and Elastic. also that you will have to add error handling to the bulk request message as it can succeed on some of the operations and fail on others.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I'm now using bulk to update ES. However, I need to update mongodb and ES after handling these two fields, so now I'm using multiple thread to update these two databases.